# Angularjs - Fire Http Post On Tab/Browser Close

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Goal**

I am using an idle timer I found on github to see if my users are AFK from the webapp. https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle

It works well and I have no issues with it. But I am unable to set the users to away if they close the browser or leave the site.

Therefore I need a way to detect if they navigate to a site that is not apart of my site and if they close browser or tab that my site is on.

**Code Below Works But Still Happens If I Redirect A Different Page On My Site**

```
    var exitEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; 

    exitEvent(chkevent, function (e) {
        DashboardService.setIdle();
        var confirmationMessage = ' ';  
        (e || window.event).returnValue = "Are you sure that you'd like to close this page?";
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
```

**Code Below Just Doesn't Work**

```
    $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        DashboardService.setIdle();
    }
```

Comment: When a user tells their browser to go to a different page, their destination is not made available to the existing page for security reasons.  You cannot determine if they are navigating to a page on your site or a page on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a way to tell if browser has closed by user.

Instead timeout created to disassoicate user on backend of application